# Creating list from single long string

Tags: python, list, sockets

I am working with TCP sockets and receiving binary packets from devices.  I am also using a module called HexToBinary that I use to convert the binary stream to a hex string.  Something like this:

```
data = self.csocket.recv(560)
convdata = HexToBinary.ByteToHex(data)
```

If I print convdata I get the string I want to see which would be something like:
"00 00 00 00 00 08 03 01 01 00 00"

What I would like to do is create a list with each byte as an element of the list so I can then modify the packet using list commands and create a new packet.  I haven't been able to figure out how to do this programatically.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry, YES Python 3.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual bytes are just `b''.join(convdata.split()).decode('hex')`. This result is a [`bytes`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytes) object, which in Python 2 is just a string, but in Python 3 is distinct from a unicode string.

Answer (score 1):

`l = [int(x, 16) for x in convdata.split()]`

assuming that the language is Python ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the intermediate `convdata`. If you want a list of bytes:

```
l = list(data)
```

If you want a list of ints:

```
l = [ord(x) for x in data]
```

Comment: So setting l = list(data) works, but I get an unformatted reply like this:  ['\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\n', '\xff', '\xfe', '\xb0', '\xee', 'E', 'h', '\xac', '\xe0', '\x00', '\x00'].  Ideally I'd want it to read 00 00 00 00 00 ff fe b0 ee ac e0 00 00.  I think this can be done with a join command but I don't know how to do it.